# Are countable dense subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to ${\mathbb Q}^n$?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and suppose $S\subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ is countable and dense. Do we have $S \cong {\mathbb Q}^n$ where both sets carry the topology inherited from the Euclidean topology on ${\mathbb R}^n$?

Comment: Related cool fact: If $n$ is allowed to be an infinite cardinal, then all countable dense subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are homeomorphic if and only if $n < \mathfrak p$. (The question has already been answered, but I thought you might like to know.)

Comment: And of corse everyone but me knows what $\mathfrak p$ is.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: The Stone-Cech remainder of the naturals, $\mathbb N^*$, has the interesting property that every nonempty $G_\delta$ set has nonempty interior. What about intersections of larger cardinality? The cardinal number $\mathfrak p$ is, by definition, the smallest cardinality of a collection of open subsets of $\mathbb N^*$ that has a nonempty intersection with empty interior. That's a formal definition. An informal definition is that $\mathfrak p$ is the cardinal where certain diagonalization-type constructions stop working. To me, that's what makes it a really interesting number.

Comment: Amazing, thanks @WillBrian! And I guess we can make this result to hold even for all $n < {\frak t}$! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1008
Example 2(c)... yes, they are all homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$!

Comment: Oh, and the reason is Sierpinski's theorem stating that every *countable, metrizable space without isolated points* is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Great - thanks for this concise answer, and it's a nice paper you pointed to!

Comment: Long ago, my friend Juliusz Jabłecki, then a high school student, wrote an article (which is apparently unavailable; I only found [this](http://web.mit.edu/rsi/compendium/final/rsicomp2003.pdf)), where he proved that any two countable subsets of a manifold are connected via a *diffeomorphism*. This preprint is cited, for example, in [an article by Maciej Pietroń](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864112004233), which deals with Hilbert's cube.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki You mean *dense* countable subsets?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes, this is what I meant, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can learn a bit more about countable dense subsets of separable metric spaces by searching for "*countable dense homogeneous space*".

A separable metric space $X$ is Countable Dense Homogeneous (CDH)
if given any two countable dense subsets $D$ and $E$ of $X$
there is a homeomorphism $f : X \rightarrow X$ such that
$f(D) = E$.

The concept was introduced by R. Bennett in
[Countable dense homogeneous spaces](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm74/fm74118.pdf)
Fund. Math., 74 (1972), pp. 189-194

Theorem 3 in the paper implies that locally euclidean spaces are CDH.
So not only any countable dense subset of ${\bf R}^n$ is homeomorphic to 
${\bf Q}^n$, but the homeomorphism can be taken as the restriction
of a global homeomorphism of ${\bf R}^n$.