# Must a continuous $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ with $\mathbb Q^n \subseteq \varphi[\mathbb Q^n]$ be surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology, irrational-numbers

Let $\varphi:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be just some continuous function.

If the image of $\varphi$ happens to contain $\mathbb Q^n$, does it follow that in fact all of $\mathbb R^n$ is contained in the image as well?

No, it does not.  For instance, the map given by
$$(x,y)\overset{\varphi}{\longmapsto} (xy-1+\pi, x^2(xy-1)+y)$$
has as its image every point in $\mathbb R^2$ except for $(\pi,0)$.

But now suppose instead that $\mathbb Q^n$ is actually contained in the image of just $\mathbb Q^n$.  That is, instead of requiring only that
$$\mathbb Q^n \subseteq \varphi[\mathbb R^n]\phantom{.}$$
we require that in fact
$$\mathbb Q^n \subseteq \varphi[\mathbb Q^n].$$

**Question.** Does it *then* follow that $\varphi[\mathbb R^n]=\mathbb R^n$, or is there a counterexample?

Comment: Yes for $n=1$. No for $n\ge 2$. For instance, for $n=2$ take the complex exponential plus an irrational ($f:z\mapsto\exp(z)+z_0$), and precompose with a self-homeomorphism of $\mathbf{R}^2$ mapping $\mathbf{Q}^2$ onto $f^{-1}(\mathbf{Q}^2)$.

Comment: @YCor : How is such a self-homeomorphism constructed?

Comment: @IosifPinelis this inverse image is dense, and $\mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbf{R}^n)$ acts transitively on dense countable subsets of $\mathbf{R}^n$ (I think the latter fact appears somewhere on MO).

Comment: @YCor : Thank you. I have indeed found this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/281159/36721 .

Comment: @YCor, since [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396148/must-a-continuous-varphi-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-rn-with-mathbb-qn-subsete#comment1014244_396148) (together with @‍IosifPinelis's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396148/must-a-continuous-varphi-mathbb-rn-to-mathbb-rn-with-mathbb-qn-subsete#comment1014253_396148)) seems to be a complete answer, maybe it could be posted as such?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A counterexample for $n=2$ is the map $\varphi(x,y) = (x,(x^2-2)y)$. Each point $(r,s)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$ is the image of $\left(r,\frac{s}{r^2-2}\right)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$, but e.g. $(\sqrt{2},1)\not\in\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: For $n\ge 2$ then take $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (x_1(x_n^2-2),x_2,\dots,x_n)$, whose inverse as birational map is $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (x_1/(x_n^2-2),x_2,\dots,x_n)$

Comment: Fabulous!  I was secretly wondering about polynomial maps, so this is extra useful for me.  Thank you!